# How to check whether a JSON File is selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check whether a JSON File is selected from the browser using `match()` function in javascript.

The below code snippet is used to check for image files:

```
<script>
var f=evt.target.files[0];
// Only process image files.
if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
  alert('Please select Image Files only!');
}
</script>
```

I want the same for JSON files.

Comment: `alert(f.type)` and see what it says.

Comment: It's showing an empty string (blank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer, 8 years later:

```js
document.querySelector('input').onchange = function ({ target: { files: [file] } }) {
  if (file.type != 'application/json') {
    alert('Please select JSON files only!');
    this.value = '';
    return;
  }

  // for displaying the contents of the file
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => console.log(result);
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

```html
<input type='file'/>
```

Actually, this only considers a file valid if it has the `.json` extension, and would consider files as invalid if they had valid `JSON` content but the wrong extension.  It would also be fooled by files with invalid `JSON` but the correct extension.

The most reliable way to validate a `JSON` file, if you must do this client-side, is calling `JSON.parse` on the contents and checking if it throws an error:

```js
const validateJSON = data => {
  try { JSON.parse(data); }
  catch { return false; }
  return true;
}

document.querySelector('input').onchange = function ({ target: { files: [file] } }) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => {
    if (!validateJSON(result)) {
      alert('Please select JSON files only!');
      this.value = '';
      return;
    }
    // display the contents of the file
    console.log(result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' />
```

Comment: Note that you can pass any type of file through this function just by giving it a `.json` extension. You still need to validate the contents of the file server-side. Similarly, it will reject valid JSON files if they don't have a `.json` extension.

Comment: Calling `JSON.parse` on the contents and checking if it throws an error would be the most reliable way to avoid the file extension issue client-side.

Comment: @GirkovArpa maybe it will be better to add this to the answer. Also, are there specific browsers where this solution would work or is it browser-agnostic?